# простой SOAP клиент + SSL > Ошибка подключения

Tags: java, ssl, soap

такая же проблема как [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36077302/failing-to-make-a-soap-request-via-ssl-with-client-certificate)

```
*** ServerHelloDone
Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication
*** Certificate chain
<Empty>
***
```

но код другой

```
    Connection conn = new Connection();
    String data = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
    "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:ns=\"SOME_URI\">" +
    "<soap:Header/><soap:Body>"+request.getParameter("data")+"</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";
    response.setContentType("text/xml; charset=\"UTF-8\"");
    String address = fias_address();
    if (address != null && !address.equals("")) {
        try {
            conn.setURL(address);
            conn.createConnection(true);
            conn.sendDataFromString(data);
            byte[] b = new byte[1024];
            int size;
            while ((size = conn.getDataStream().read(b)) != -1)
                response.getOutputStream().write(b, 0, size);
            conn.closeInputStream();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

в классе Connection

```
public void createConnection(Boolean isSecure) {
    try {
        secure = isSecure;
        if (isSecure) {
            setSystemSecurityConnectionProperties();
            con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            ((HttpsURLConnection) con).setRequestMethod("POST");
            HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return fias.HostnameVerifier.DEFAULT.verify(hostname, session);
                }
            };
            ((HttpsURLConnection) con).setHostnameVerifier(hv);
        } else
            con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void sendDataFromString(String data) {
    OutputStream os = null;
    if (secure)
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=\"UTF-8\"");
    else
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=\"UTF-8\"");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(data.length()));
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setUseCaches(false);
    try {
        os = con.getOutputStream();
        os.write(data.getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            os.flush();
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

поднимал тестовый сервер с простым сервлетом для ответа и своими сертификатами - соединяется нормально,а вот на удалённом сервере не соединяется с сервером SOAP чужим.  доступа никакого на SOAP нет

для тестов использую форму,через которую отсылаю данные на сервлет,он собирает всё в единую строку (XML) и отправляет дальше на SOAP сервер
при попытке установить соединение - не может подключиться и в логах самый первый код с Warning и со стороны сервера закрывается соединение

```
http-nio-8090-exec-1, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
%% Invalidated:  [Session-2, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
http-nio-8090-exec-1, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
http-nio-8090-exec-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 32
http-nio-8090-exec-1, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
http-nio-8090-exec-1, called closeSocket()
http-nio-8090-exec-1, called close()
http-nio-8090-exec-1, called closeInternal(true)
```

Comment: Лучше приведите описание проблемы, а не ссылку.

Comment: да я вроде всё написал сразу ... сейчас дополнил